# using scanner and delimeter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to scan a series of lines from a .txt file that looks like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Yf7.png) 
to make an output like the following: "[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S9VB.png)

Here is my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\a1.txt"));
String wordbuffer="";

while(scan.hasNext()) {
   scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
   wordbuffer+=scan.next();
   System.out.println(wordbuffer);

   if(scan.next==" "){
       wordbuffer="";
   }
}
scan.close();
```

Comment: 1) Don't change delimiter between `hasNext()` and `next()`. --- 2) Since input is one character per line, including a space on a blank line, use `nextLine()`, not `next()`, to read lines.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Why did you believe ``\Z`` *([The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds))* would be a good delimiter here?

Comment: please do not post a screenshot of text - hard to read and even harder to copy... (and blocked in some environments)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger okay,thanks on advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Add:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {             
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\a.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        String s=in.nextLine();
        if (s.equals(""))               
           sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        else
            sb.append(s);           
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println( sb.toString());
    }
```

> Output:

```
stack 
o2 
flow
```

Comment: sorry dude, it was my mistake, SO format my string, i edited now